# Laravel7　マイグレーションのエラー　General error: 3780

Tags: laravel

Laravel7

マイグレーションしたいのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。このエラーをしらべるとたいていは`$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();`や`$table->unsignedBigInteger()`による解決方法が出てきますが、それをやっての結果です。
他の解決不能なエラーが出ていたためデータベースを削除して、`php artisan migrate`ということを数回やりましたが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'user_group_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `user_group` add constraint `user_group_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

      +9 vendor frames
  10  database/migrations/2020_06_11_152935_create_user_groups_table.php:19
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("create")

      +22 vendor frames
  33  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

目的はチャットアプリを作ることで、テーブル構成は以下で、中間テーブルとgroups,commentsは`php make:migration`しました。usersは`php artisan ui vue --auth`をして作られたテーブルです。

users<-->中間テーブル(user_groups)<-->groups
　　　　　　　　　　　↑
　　　　　　　　　　　↓
　　　　　　　　   comments

↓はdatabase/migrations/2020_06_11_152935_create_user_groups_table.phpです。

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserGroupsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('group_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
            $table->unique(['user_id', 'group_id'], 'uq_user_groups');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_groups');
    }
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

外部キーの対象となる側のidをincrements('id')で設定していたので、create_user_groups_table.phpでは$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();とすればよいだけでした。